# Expandable List GroupView's Arrow needs to be aligned with text not centered in View

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, expandablelistview

I currently have defined a `ExpandableListView` that will allow my second `GroupView` list to contain a title above it. However This does not look appealing to the user because the flow of the expansion arrow is not aligned with the text but rather in the center of the view. Does anyone have any subquestions on what I could do to make this look more appealing? I need to have a header after the second group.

[image]

**This code is what sets up my `GroupView` in my custom adapter.**

```
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView groupTitle = null;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = null;
    if(groupPosition == 1){
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_first_major_language_group_row, null);
    } else {
        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_language_group_row, null);
    }
    groupTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text_element);
    String myText = this.getGroup(groupPosition).toString();
    groupTitle.setText(myText);

    return v;
}
```

**custom_language_group_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_element"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:text = "Language Group Name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**custom_first_major_language_group_row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
         <TextView 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:text="Major Languages"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#fff" 
        android:id="@+id/majorLanguageTitle" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_element"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dip"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/majorLanguageTitle"
        android:text = "Language Group Name"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If you have any ideas of how I can get the drop down arrow to align with the text it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Having the same problem... I was so excited when I saw your post.  I thought I might get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So my answer is a somewhat lame answer.  I had that problem but I noticed that mine text was off centered only by about 4-5 dp's (after testing).  So instead of moving the expand/collapse image to be centered correctly, I center the text and then add bottom margin to the text view of 5dp.  So now my textview appears to be much closer in line with the expand/collapse image.

Not the preferred solution but it worked for me.